# What is location of user login logs?

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, logs, login

I want to know the details of user logins of my Gnu/Linux servers (RHEL7 and Ubuntu 16.04) e.g. who, from what IP, when. So what is the location of the log files, from which I can find the list of the users and details of the last 30 days.

I also want to redirect these logs on another location (ftp://IP/logindetails). So please guide me, How can I make it possible?

Comment: What distro? The defaults vary.

Comment: On RHEL 7 and Ubuntu both

Comment: `/var/log/auth.log` on ubuntu, `/var/log/secure` on RHEL

Comment: Thanks, Can I redirect these on another location like ftp site or shared drive

Comment: Most people use the system's syslog daemon (the rsyslog or syslog-ng daemon) to send the logs to a remote system that is listening on the syslog port.  It would be a lot easier than creating a whole new service to copy the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs themselves vary by distro but are usually found in `/var/log/`.

Examples
`/var/log/utmp`, `/var/log/btmp`, `/var/log/wtmp` `/var/log/secure`

Among those, `utmp` shows system information and status as well as terminal logins.

`btmp` shows failed logins. `/var/log/faillog` may have this as well

`/var/log/auth` shows PAM summaries, including authentication and login.

See [utmp on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp) for more information.

See [AskUbuntu - How to See Login History?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390201/how-to-see-login-history)

For copying, you can use `ftp` to transfer the files, or you could directly copy them over using `scp` or `rsync`

Answer (score 0):

RHEL login details can be found in:
`/var/log/wtmp`

Ubuntu login details can be found in:
`/var/log/auth.log`

You could run a cron job to copy the logfile to your ftp server

```
crontab -e
0 0 * * * curl -T /var/log/<logfile> ftp://IP/logindetails --user user:secret
```

You just need to specify the logfile and user information for the cronjob. This would copy the logfile over every day at midnight.