# Displaying users logged in today between two dates

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have two times, for example: 12:48 and 16:29. How can I list the users logged in from 12:48 to 16:29?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is location of user login logs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345787/what-is-location-of-user-login-logs)

Answer (score 3):

Use `last` command with `-s` and `-t` or `-p` flags:

```
 -s, --since <time>   display the lines since the specified time
 -t, --until <time>   display the lines until the specified time
 -p, --present <time> display who were present at the specified time
```

---

```bsh
last -s "12:48" -t "16:29"
last -p "12:48"
```

Note, the first command won't show present logins!

---

```
TIME FORMATS
       The options that take the time argument understand the following formats:

       YYYYMMDDhhmmss
       YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
       YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm     (seconds will be set to 00)
       YYYY-MM-DD           (time will be set to 00:00:00)
       hh:mm:ss             (date will be set to today)
       hh:mm                (date will be set to today, seconds to 00)
       now
       yesterday            (time is set to 00:00:00)
       today                (time is set to 00:00:00)
       tomorrow             (time is set to 00:00:00)
       +5min
       -5days
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!